# gtag.js is recording $0 for all goals' Conversion value and Enhanced Commerce data is missing

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js, google-ad-manager

We recently upgraded our `analytics.js` tracking to `gtag.js` approach to consolidate tracking across Google Analytics and Google Ads.

However, after the migration, Google Analytics no longer displays any Enhanced E-commerce results. Further, even though it does show the correct number of Goal Completions, the Goal value is $0. Also, in Google Ads' "Measurements > Conversions > Tracking status" shows "No recent conversions".

Here is what the script looks like:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-68451836-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-68451836-1');
    gtag("config", "AW-955498876");

    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-955498876/p6noCPiZmmAQ_ILPxwM',
        'value': 18.74,
        'currency': 'NZD',
        'transaction_id': '10723.xn3TfOHYHWjqdXCMGwZJ4YnhmjI',
    });

    gtag('event', 'purchase', {
        'transaction_id': '10723.xn3TfOHYHWjqdXCMGwZJ4YnhmjI',
        'value': 18.74,
        'currency': 'NZD',
        'tax': 2.44,
        'shipping': 10.92,
        'items': [
            {
                'id': 'LA',
                'name': 'Large format prints',
                'variant': '7x11 print_as_is pro_satin',
                'category': 'prints',
                'price': 7.82,
                'quantity': 1,
                'list_position': 1
            },
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Here is a link to our order confirmation page: https://happymoose.nz/thankyou?order_id=10722.B137Yp6kMc90RaSfnlZMqp-porQ

I have also double-checked that the `UA-` and `AW-` accounts are correct.

Thanks for any help/hints you may have.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I believe wrapping all the code in one script may be messing with it as the conversion script tells the headset script what to do so they should have their own script tags around them. In addition you had double quotes around your AW configuration.

Do not add a transaction ID to the google ads script.

Also would be good if you can share a picture of the goal set up in google analytics.

Hope this helps.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-68451836-1"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-68451836-1');
gtag('config', 'AW-955498876');
</script>

<script>
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
    'send_to': 'AW-955498876/p6noCPiZmmAQ_ILPxwM',
    'value': 18.74,
    'currency': 'NZD'
    });
</script>

<script>
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    'transaction_id': '10723.xn3TfOHYHWjqdXCMGwZJ4YnhmjI',
    'value': 18.74,
    'currency': 'NZD',
    'tax': 2.44,
    'shipping': 10.92,
    'items': [
        {
            'id': 'LA',
            'name': 'Large format prints',
            'variant': '7x11 print_as_is pro_satin',
            'category': 'prints',
            'price': 7.82,
            'quantity': 1,
            'list_position': 1
        },
    ]
});
</script>
```